# Junit lookup from a list and assert their order

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, hamcrest

Say I have a list of apple "listOfApples".

```
class apple {
    int serial;
    int price;
    ......
}
```

Multiple apple may have same serial. I have to make sure that all the apples in listOfApples are sorted based on their serial. 
More precisely all apples from listOfApples that have serial 0 are in the front of the list.
How can I test listOfApples whether it keep the apple in order or not using junit ?

Comment: Have you actually tried anything? What happened? Give a [mcve].

Comment: And read about java coding conventions. Class names start upper case. And yes, your question is really missing key information. Please spend some time at the [help] to learn how things work here. Definitely not like this.

Answer (score 2):

This seems relatively straightforward - just test that the list is the same before and after it has been sorted:

```
List<Apple> sortedApples = new ArrayList<>(listOfApples);
sortedApples.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.serial));
assertEquals(sortedApples, listOfApples);
```

If the two lists are equal then the original list was correctly sorted.

Addition:

Good pickup by @Harmlezz in the comments: this test could fail even though the original list is correctly sorted. An alternative is:

```
assertTrue(IntStream.range(1, sortedAppples.size())
    .allMatch(i -> sortedApples.get(i).serial >= sortedApples.get(i-1).serial));
```

Comment: This is the way to go. A `List` is equal to another `List` if it contains the same items in the same order. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Thanks friend @sprinter.

Seems to me it'll work. I'll check it and obviously inform you.

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer, apples having the same serial may appear at different positions in the list after sorting which may result in the test to fail.

Comment: @sprinter: now I like your second solution more than mine :-) It even works for the case, when `sortedApples` is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the fact that apples may have the same serial, you can't rely on sorting of lists, because apples having the same serial may appear at unpredictable positions: Hence try:

```
@Test
public void testOrderingOfProvidedApples() {
    int serial = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (Apple apple : listOfApples()) {
        assertTrue(apple.getSerial() >= serial);
        serial = apple.getSerial();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Harmlezz. It worked.